Audio Recording Javascript Chrome extension working with Youtube but not working on Google Meet Mic to record audio
I have fully working code which starts, stop recording audio from a tab. It also plays and download the most recent recorded audio. I tested it both Youtube and Google Meet. It captures the speaker output but when I try to capture mic audio from Google Meet, it fails. What should I be modifying in the code so that it captures both mic as well speaker audio in SEPERATE files as mic.wav and speaker.wav?
Manifest.json
{
  "name": "Audio Recorder",
  "description": "Records audio (speaker + Mic) of current tab in an offscreen document.",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "116",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "not-recording.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["offscreen", "contextMenus", "activeTab", "tabCapture", "tabs", "storage", "cookies"]
}

offscreen.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.target === 'offscreen') {
    switch (message.type) {
      case 'start-recording':
        startRecording(message.data);
        break;
      case 'stop-recording':
        stopRecording();
        break;
      case 'play-audio':
        playAudio();
        break;
      case 'download-audio':
        downloadAudio();
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unrecognized message:', message.type);
    }
  } else if (message.type === 'check-audio') {
    sendResponse({ audioAvailable: audioBlobs.length > 0 });
    return true;
  }
});

let recorder;
let data = [];
let audioBlobs = []; // Array to store audio blobs

async function startRecording(streamId) {
  if (recorder?.state === 'recording') {
    throw new Error('Called startRecording while recording is in progress.');
  }

  // Request tab audio
  const tabAudio = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
      }
    }
  });

  let micAudio;
  try {
    // Attempt to request microphone audio
    micAudio = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true // Request microphone audio
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn('Microphone not available or permission denied:', error);
    micAudio = null; // Set micAudio to null if not available
  }

  // Combine the audio streams if microphone is available
  const combinedStream = micAudio 
    ? new MediaStream([...tabAudio.getAudioTracks(), ...micAudio.getAudioTracks()])
    : tabAudio; // Use only tab audio if mic is not available

  const output = new AudioContext();
  const source = output.createMediaStreamSource(combinedStream);
  source.connect(output.destination);

  recorder = new MediaRecorder(combinedStream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });
  recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => data.push(event.data);
  recorder.onstop = () => {
    const blob = new Blob(data, { type: 'audio/webm' });
    audioBlobs.push(blob); // Store the blob in the array
    data = [];
  };
  recorder.start();

  window.location.hash = 'recording';
}

async function stopRecording() {
  recorder.stop();
  recorder.stream.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
  window.location.hash = '';
}

function playAudio() {
  if (audioBlobs.length > 0) {
    const lastBlob = audioBlobs[audioBlobs.length - 1];
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(lastBlob);
    const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
    audio.play();
  } else {
    console.error('No audio available to play.');
  }
}

function downloadAudio() {
  if (audioBlobs.length > 0) {
    const lastBlob = audioBlobs[audioBlobs.length - 1];
    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(lastBlob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = audioUrl;
    a.download = 'recording.webm';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  } else {
    console.error('No audio available to download.');
  }
}

popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const isRecording = localStorage.getItem('isRecording') === 'true';

  document.getElementById('startButton').disabled = isRecording;
  document.getElementById('stopButton').disabled = !isRecording;

  // Check if there are any audio recordings stored
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'check-audio' }, (response) => {
    const audioAvailable = response.audioAvailable;
    document.getElementById('playButton').disabled = !audioAvailable;
    document.getElementById('downloadButton').disabled = !audioAvailable;
  });
});

document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  document.getElementById('startButton').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('stopButton').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('playButton').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('downloadButton').disabled = true;

  localStorage.setItem('isRecording', 'true');

  const existingContexts = await chrome.runtime.getContexts({});
  let offscreenDocument = existingContexts.find(
    (c) => c.contextType === 'OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT'
  );

  if (!offscreenDocument) {
    await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
      url: 'offscreen.html',
      reasons: ['USER_MEDIA'],
      justification: 'Recording from chrome.tabCapture API'
    });
  }

  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  const streamId = await chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId({ targetTabId: tab.id });

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'start-recording',
    target: 'offscreen',
    data: streamId
  });
});

document.getElementById('stopButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('startButton').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('stopButton').disabled = true;

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'stop-recording',
    target: 'offscreen'
  }, () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'check-audio' }, (response) => {
      const audioAvailable = response.audioAvailable;
      document.getElementById('playButton').disabled = !audioAvailable;
      document.getElementById('downloadButton').disabled = !audioAvailable;
    });
  });

  localStorage.setItem('isRecording', 'false');
});

document.getElementById('playButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'play-audio',
    target: 'offscreen'
  });
});

document.getElementById('downloadButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'download-audio',
    target: 'offscreen'
  });
});


Oh! My bad. I wasn't aware. Any workaround where I can capture the input going into Google Meet Mic though? I mean if it's capturing some element, we can capture it too right? @redoc

Not sure but checkout all links, code here . Sorry you may be able to record simultaneously..

Oh yes. I actually pointed to that one too. But I'm not able to understand the code. The github code seems to be in react.
